# select html till i reach a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have a html like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>a2</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>b1</td>
<td>b2</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>c2</td>

</tr>

<tr class="total">
<td>d1</td>
<td>d2</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>e1</td>
<td>e2</td>

</tr>





</table>
```

now i want to select only the html till i reach 'total' class, so the hmtl i want jquery to select is:

```
<tr>
<td>a1</td>
<td>a2</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>b1</td>
<td>b2</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>c2</td>

</tr>

<tr class="total">
<td>d1</td>
<td>d2</td>

</tr>
```

the code i tried for this was:

```
console.log($("table .total").parentsUntil("table").html());
```

but this gives all the tr's (that is, including e1,e2 rows, which i dont want)

if i had gotten the correct html, (ie, till d series), i would perform an action on the each of the tr's to get a perticular value (i mean for ex i want a1, b1, c1, and d1 only, not e1, so i put total class on the d series only).

can anyone help me to get only html till 'total'?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: maybe something like `console.log($("table tr.total").prevUntil("table").html())` will help you

Comment: What's the starting element? Or you want to cover the whole table?

Comment: starting element is the table only.i want to cover the html till total class, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will serve your purpose!

```
var neededHTML = "";
var allHTML = "";
$('table tr').each(function(){
    allHTML += $(this).get(0).outerHTML;
    if ($(this).hasClass('total')){
        neededHTML = allHTML;
    }
})
console.log(neededHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. `$("table tr.total").prevUntil("table")` does indeed give you the set of `<tr>` elements preceding the selected `tr` element.

<sub>You could even use `$("table tr.total").prevAll()` for this as it doesn't explore the parent elements.</sub>

You can create an array from the returned `tr` elements using `Array.from`, and generate an array of the outer HTML string of each `tr` using `Array#map`.

<sub>Note that [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is not supported in IE11. An alternative would be to iterate the elements using a `for` loop.</sub>

Finally, you can join them using `Array#join`.

```js
console.log($("table tr.total").prevUntil("table"));
console.log(
  Array.from(
    $("table tr.total").prevAll()
  ).map(t => t.outerHTML).join("")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="total">
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>e1</td>
    <td>e2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives you:

```
"0": <tr>…</tr>
"1": <tr>…</tr>
"2": <tr>…</tr>
```

```js
console.log($("tr.total").prevUntil("table", "tr"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="total">
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e1</td>
    <td>e2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Established what is excluded:

```
var exc = $('.total').nextAll('tr').add('.total');
```

Then collect everything **but** the exclusions.

```
var inc = $('tr').not(exc);
```

## Demo

```js
/* Get All <tr> after `.total` and add `.total` 
|| as well
*/
var exc = $('.total').nextAll('tr').add('.total');

/* Get all <tr> but not the <tr> in the exc var */
var inc = $('tr').not(exc);

// Just to demonstarte that it worked
inc.css('background', 'cyan');
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="total">
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e1</td>
    <td>e2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```